# Whether the closed subset of measurable set is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $X$ is a measurable set , $U$ is a closed subset of $X$. Is $U$ measurable?

I think the answer should be yes, but I don't know how to proof it .

Comment: Close of $X$ or closure of $X$?

Comment: @Euler88...   closed set of $X$

Comment: In which measurable space? Closed sets are always Borel (measurable).

Comment: What's the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Hint: How do relatively closed sets look like? They have a special form.

Comment: @user251257   Thanks ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Theorem.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Set_Measurable_in_Borel_Sigma-Algebra)** Let $(S,τ)$ be a topological space, and let $B(τ)$ be the associated Borel $σ$-algebra.

Let $C$ be a closed set in $S$.

Then $C$ is [$B(τ)$-measurable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Borel_Sigma-Algebra).

Indeed your question rise in Caratheodory's criterion. For more detail and a straight proof see [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/rjerrard/1501/notes/week1.pdf).